# Update data in access ado net

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-access, ado.net

Let me tell you, I'm just learning.

There is an Access table that is displayed in the datagrid in wpf. I'm trying to change the data in wpf so that they write to the access table, but I get an error. Did by analogy with localdb Code below

```
 var accessUpdate = $@"UPDATE ORDERS SET 
                   email = @emailAccess,
                   product_number = @product_number, 
                   product_name = @product_name
                   WHERE Id = @idAccess";

        daAccess.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand(accessUpdate, accessConnection);
        daAccess.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@emailAccess", OleDbType.WChar, 0, "email");
        daAccess.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@product_number", OleDbType.WChar, 0, "product_number");
        daAccess.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@product_name", OleDbType.WChar, 0, "product_name");
```

wpf

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="gridViewAccess" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding}"  
                      CurrentCellChanged="ChangedAccess" 
                      CellEditEnding="ChangedEndingAccess" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      CanUserAddRows="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="idAccess" 
                                Binding="{Binding Id}" 
                                Header="Id" 
                                IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="emailAccess" 
                                Binding="{Binding email}" 
                                Header="email"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="product_number" 
                                Binding="{Binding product_number}" 
                                Header="Код товара"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="product_name" 
                                Binding="{Binding product_name}" 
                                Header="Наименование товара"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
```

ChangedAccess and ChangedEndingAccess

```
private void ChangedAccess(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
        if (drAccess == null) return;
        drAccess.EndEdit();
        daAccess.Update(dtAccess);
}


private void ChangedEndingAccess(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    drAccess = (DataRowView)gridViewAccess.SelectedItem;
    drAccess.BeginEdit();
}


DataTable dtAccess;
OleDbDataAdapter daAccess;
DataRowView drAccess;
```

if i add `daAccess.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@idAccess", OleDbType.Integer, 0, "Id");`

The error `"Data type mismatch in criteria expression."`

id type is integer

[id field properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFMEB.png)

how can i fix this

Comment: > if i add `daAccess.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@idAccess", OleDbType.Integer, 0, "Id");`  -

That code adding string "Id" value into parameter with type `OleDbType.Integer`. It's a mistake.

Comment: @SergeyNazarov I understand that the problem is in this line, but I don’t understand how it should be, it needs to write the changes in the line where from the database is equal to the id from the date grid

Comment: Ok. In all cases in your code, you passing string as value of parameter via `Add` method. I mean "Id" is not a value from your form, like "email", and on and on.
Last argument in `Add` method is a value of `IDataParameter`. You should extract it from form, convert to right type, `int` in this case, and pass into `Add` method. Not "Id" string.